# bullet ( <ol> ) position goes down after changing line height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have bullet list:

```
          <ol className="graphkregular mt-2" style={{ display: "listItem" }}>
            <li>
              <small>{popupData.content[0].split("\n").join("\n")}</small>
            </li>
            <li className='mt-2'>
              <small>{popupData.content[1].split("\n").join("\n")}</small>
            </li>
          </ol>
```

after changing line height and display bullets go down:

```
small {
  line-height: 1.4em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

how to fix this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing margin top from ol tag's classname

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `display: inline-block;` from small tag.